# Unit test for the 'none' type in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertion, nonetype

How would I go about testing for a function that does not return anything?

For example, say I have this function:

```
def is_in(char):
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(char)
```

and then if I were to test it:

```
class TestIsIn(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
    ''' Test if one character was added to the list'''
    self.assertEqual(self.is_in('a'), # And this is where I am lost)
```

I don't know what to assert the function is equal to, since there isn't any return value that I could compare it to.

Would *assertIn* work?

Answer (score 39):

All Python functions return something. If you don't specify a return value, `None` is returned. So if your goal really is to make sure that something doesn't return a value, you can just say

```
self.assertIsNone(self.is_in('a'))
```

(However, this can't distinguish between a function without an explicit return value and one which does `return None`.)

Answer (score 4):

The point of a unit test is to test something that the function does.  If it's not returning a value, then what is it actually doing? In this case, it doesn't appear to be doing anything, since `my_list` is a local variable, but if your function actually looked something like this:

```
def is_in(char, my_list):
    my_list.append(char)
```

Then you would want to test if `char` is actually appended to the list.  Your test would be:

```
def test_one(self):
    my_list = []
    is_in('a', my_list)
    self.assertEqual(my_list, ['a'])
```

Since the function does not return a value, there isn't any point testing for it (unless you need make sure that it doesn't return a value).