# Testing methods that return nothing, XML, Python

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing

I'm trying to understand why, how, and if to unit test methods that seem to return nothing. I've read in a couple other threads that:

> The point of a unit test is to test something that the function does. If its not returning a value, then what is it actually doing?

[unittest for none type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868170/unittest-for-none-type-in-python)

In my example, I am using the `XMLSigner` and `XMLVerifier` from the `sign_XML` library.

```
def verify_xml(signed_xml: str, cert_file: str) -> None:
    with open(cert_file, 'rb') as file:
        cert = file.read()
    with open(signed_xml, 'rb') as input_file:
        input_data = input_file.read()
    XMLVerifier().verify(input_data, x509_cert=cert)
```

I started looking up documentaion I found for [SignXML](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/signxml/latest/signxml.pdf). I read that **verify()**:

> **class signxml.XMLVerifier** Create a new XML Signature Verifier object,
>   which can be used to hold configuration information and verify
>   multiple pieces of data. verify(data, require_x509=True,
>   x509_cert=None, cert_subject_name=None, ca_pem_file=None,
>   ca_path=None, hmac_key=None, validate_schema=True, parser=None,
>   uri_resolver=None, id_attribute=None, expect_references=1)
>
> Verify the
>   XML signature supplied in the data and return the XML node signed by
>   the signature, or raise an exception if the signature is not valid. By
>   default, this requires the signature to be generated using a valid
>   X.509 certificate.

This is my first time working with this and I'm confused even more now. So this apparently does return something.

**What I've attempted**

For another method which ends up calling `verify_xml` I've used @patch and just checked that the method I patched was called and with the correct arguments. This also seems like it's not the way to do it, but I didn't know how else to test it.

It feels weird doing something similar with the `verify_xml` method and just checking that it has been called once.

I've also tried  `self.assertIsNone...` and that passes but that seems weird to me and not like it's a way one does this.

Could someone help me understand why, how, and if to unit test methods that seem to return nothing).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to test `verify_xml()` is to test the Exception triggered by `XMLVerifer().verify()` if input parameters is not valid

There are a few types of exceptions you can tested.

```
from signxml import (XMLSigner, XMLVerifier, InvalidInput, InvalidSignature, InvalidCertificate, InvalidDigest)


class TestVerifyXML(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpCls(cls):
        cls.signed_xml = from_magic()
        cls.cert_file = from_magic2()
        cls.ceft_file_bad = from_magic_bad() 

    def test_verify_xml(self):

        # no Exception with correct xml
        verify_xml(self.signed_xml, self.cert_file)

        with self.assertRaises(InvalidSignature):
            verify_xml(self.signed_xml, self.cert_file_bad)
```